# form doesn't submit when requirements are met

Tags: javascript, function, validation, if-statement, passwords

So I am having trouble getting my form to submit after the requirements are met. I tried to force submit with HTMLFormElement.submit(), but nothing seems to be working other than the validation itself.

---

```
<script>
        const uid = document.getElementById("userId")
        const fname = document.getElementById("fname")
        const lname = document.getElementById("lname")
        const birthday = document.getElementById("date")
        const form = document.getElementById("form")

        form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
            let lowerCase = /[a-z]/g
            let upperCase = /[A-Z]/g
            let errors = [""]
            if (uid.value.length < 7 || uid.value.length > 12) {
                errors.push("Error in Length")
                alert("User ID must be between 8 and 12 characters")
            }
            if (!(uid.value.match(lowerCase))) {
                errors.push("Error in character case")
                alert("User ID must contain at least 1 lowercase letter")
            }
            if (!(uid.value.match(upperCase))) {
                errors.push("Error in character case")
                alert("User ID must contain at least 1 Uppercase letter")
            }
            if (errors.length > 0) {
                event.preventDefault()
            }// else {
            //     // HTMLFormElement.submit()
            //     // errors = 0;
            //     // document.forms["form"].submit()
            // }
        });
```

Comment: @Barmar that's what I thought, maybe I have a hidden bug or something in my html or script. I'll try looking through it again. Thank you!

Comment: What's the point of the `errors` array? You push into it, but you never use the contents. You could just use a boolean `has_errors` variable that you initialize to `false` and change to `true` if any of the validations fail.

Comment: This guy right here single handedly changed my life I am forever in your debt @Barmar. I don't know why or how I couldn't think of something so brilliant. That actually fixed the problem perfectly! I wish I could send you the new code snippet, but I don't want to trouble you any further. I really really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

`errors.length` will always be more than 0 because you're initializing it with 1 element (an empty string). Change

```
let errors = [""]
```

to

```
let errors = []
```